# Packet filtering in Windows (XP, 7 etc)

Tags: windows, winapi, packet-sniffers

How can i filter (allow, deny etc) outgoing packets in Windows? I want to search in TCP or UDP packet types to find in the data segment for example this "387602304fd236e048125453b1fa10c980e9dad4fa7f3f5dd2497c2e8b2b" and drop/block/deny the packet, if it matches the search hex string.
I have already tried WIPFW and PKTFILTER but they only serve IP source, dest, port etc filtering. They don't inspect the packet's data.
I think Berkeley Packet Filter doe's that job, but it's for unix...

Answer (score 2):

Here is some to filter packet in windows:

[WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/divert.html) Free open source project work on Windows 7, 2008 or upper. network layer.

[WinpkFilter 3.0](http://www.ntkernel.com/w&p.php?id=7) Commercial, Windows XP and upper. datalink layer

[pcausa](http://pcausa.com/), Commercial. datalink layer

[Windows Filtering Platform Packet Modification Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
A sample to create callout driver that WinDivert use, you should now to implement kernel driver. network layer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) in windows.

Starting from version 1.10, you can filter unwanted TCP/IP activity during the capture process (Capture Filter), or when displaying the captured TCP/IP data (Display Filter)

Comment: It does about the same as WIPFW and PKTFILTER. I don't want to filter the results that are displayed to me during the capture process, but to intercept the packet and modify it or drop it.

Let me explain better to you. Let's say we have a simple chat program like msn messenger. I send a message to you "Hello Max". I want the packet filtering program to search my outgoing packets, find the packet that contains "Hello Max", and change it (so you will receive "Hello Dan") or drop it (so you won't receive anything).

Answer (score 0):

You want application level filtering then, (just changing the payload). If you want to be able to drop, I know you can hook into Winsock, which will allow you to capture packets as they go out and set up a filter there. Windows seven also added to their firewall, so you could use that API to grab outbound packets; I'm not sure if it will allow you to specifically alter the payload data, though.

Comment: Thanks, i will try the winsock2 interception method as the windows 7 advanced firewall, doesn't offer the ability to change packets.

Comment: Ok solution found. Check this -> http://wpepro.net/index.php?categoryid=4&p13_sectionid=1&p13_fileid=1016