# How can one do packet filtering in Windows(2003,XP, etc) efficiently

Tags: windows, networking, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

The old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978721/packet-filtering-in-windows-xp-7-etc) is here. But I still cannot find useful solutions in the question so that I rewrite this question here.

How can i filter (allow, deny etc) outgoing packets in Windows? I want to filter IP packets through particular bits eg. the BPF rule IP[2:2] > 189. And then transmitted these filtered packages to other programs to resolve the packets.  But I read the information on [Windows Filtering Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510(v=vs.85).aspx), it allow developers to write a middleware which I think it is hard for me to do.

So is there a relative way to filter packets in Windows xp or 2003 and then transmitted the packets to other applications?

Comment: So you know the solution, decided, that it is too hard for you, and now ask for a simpler solution? I'm never going to understand what drives developers down that line of thought (or, really, complete lack thereof).

Comment: Yeath, right now I just want to use [winpcap](https://www.winpcap.org/), and just send interesting packets to the upper application.